# how to insert caption to table and figure in aspose.word

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, caption, aspose.words

I want to create a table of figure and table of tables but first tables and figures should have caption to be Identify.and I need to insert caption to tables and figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using the following code.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx"); 
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

// Insert caption above the Table
builder.MoveTo(doc.FirstSection.Body.Tables[0].PreviousSibling);
builder.Write("Table: ");
builder.InsertField(@"SEQ Table \* ARABIC", "");

// Insert caption below the Figure
builder.MoveToDocumentEnd();
builder.InsertParagraph();
builder.Write("Figure: ");
builder.InsertField(@"SEQ Figure \* ARABIC", "");

doc.UpdateFields();

doc.Save(MyDir + @"17.11.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: so thanks but System.ArgumentNullException occurred on "builder.MoveTo(doc.FirstSection.Body.Tables[0].PreviousSibling);"

Comment: Please ZIP and upload your **input** Word document and **expected** Word document showing the final result on Dropbox and share the download link here for testing. You can create expected Word document by using MS Word for our reference. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.